# В чем ошибки получения информации из потока и в преобразовании форматов?

Tags: python

```
from threading import Thread
data_from_file=[]

def thread_read (file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        str1=f.read()
        f.close
        data_from_file.append(str1)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_r="read_thread.txt"
    new_th1=Thread (target=thread_read,args=(file_r,))
    new_th1.start()
    input()   
    str_r=str(data_from_file)
    print('str_r:', str_r)
```

С удовольствием изучаю Python. В учебной задаче столкнулся с непонятным поведением моего скрипта. Уже несколько часов копаюсь, отладкой конкретизировал проблему, но дальше застрял. Просьба помочь:

- Почему скрипт работает относительно верно, только если ввести
  искусственную задержку - input()? (что нужно вместо задержки или хоть
  что я не изучил? :-)
- Я вообще правильный метод для возвращения результата из потока выбрал через внешнюю
  переменную? (Ввел список для возвращения, так как в StackOverflow на
  вопрос, как передать результат потока в main, советовали (не мне)
  такой подход.)
- Обновление: Этот вопрос отвечен ниже:"Почему даже при правильной работе финальный результат при печати строки получается не: 'Тест', а ['Тест']?" Спасибо Эникейщику!

**Детали:**

- Задача: чтение из файла потоком, возврат результата в main.
- Файл read_thread содержит слово "Тест".
- Поставил отладочную печать print и отладочный input:
  если запускать без input, то результат отладочной печати - неверный: str_r: []
  если запускать c input, то вернее: str_r: ['Тест']

Comment: вы во второй строчке создаете список, а потом удивляетесь, почему у вас результат список?

Comment: Спасибо, но я не этому удивляюсь. Я же пытаюсь его в строку преобразовать через  str_r=str(data_from_file). И спасибо. Надо join () использовать.

Comment: если преобразовать список [2, 3]  в строку, то в строке будет ``[2, 3]``, а не ``23``. Т.е. будет список в текстовом виде, а не содержимое этого списка.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое за подсказку. Т.е. результат у меня всё же строка, да не та, что я ожидал, так как неверно преобразовывал. Верно так: " ".join(map(str, [2, 3]))
Правда, вопросы 1 и 3 сломали мне голову гораздо больше:-)
Если поделителсь мудростью и тут, будет здорово.

Comment: Вот представте себе дорогу по ней едит машина это основной поток. C помощью Thread вы создали запустили еще один поток вторая машинка которая едит чуть позади первой. То на финише мы получим 'неверный: str_r: []'. А что мы притоморзим первую машинку  с помощью input() вторая вырвется в перед и на финише мы имеем  'str_r: ['Тест']'

Comment: Спасибо. Я об этом догадывался, потому input () и вставил. А делать-то что нужно, чтобы правильно передать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, используя [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) и [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#future-objects):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def thread_read(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        return f.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_r="read_thread.txt"
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future = executor.submit(thread_read, file_r)  
        # тут будет ожидание, пока thread_read не сделает return
        # и это значение вернет result()
        str_r=future.result()
    print('str_r:', str_r)
```

Или чисто потоками:

```
from threading import Thread

def thread_read(file_name, value_holder):
    with open(file_name, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        value_holder[0] = f.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_r = "read_thread.txt"
    result_holder = [None]
    new_th1 = Thread(target=thread_read, args=(file_r, result_holder))
    new_th1.start()
    # далее ключевой момент - ждем когда new_th1 закончит выполнение
    new_th1.join()
    print("str_r:", result_holder[0])
```

> Я вообще правильный метод для возвращения результата из потока выбрал через внешнюю переменную

Этот способ плох тем, что требует использования глобальной переменной. Лучше как во втором примере, а еще лучше использовать более высокоуровневые средства как Future или Queue.

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо!